# real time edit html code in vim and show in pyqt4's QWebView

Tags: vim, pyqt4

I like edit html code in vim, but view the effect is labour. I need to save file, open the html file in browser, it waster time. I don't like coding in dw, is has no vim features.
then I want to  develop a tool that using pyqt4's QwebView to monitor the vim's buffer in memory. thus, when I coding in vim, QwebView could display the effect as soon as I type code, it's prossible?.
just like this [real time html editor](http://htmledit.squarefree.com/).

Answer (score 3):

[This plugin](https://github.com/suan/vim-instant-markdown) does real time markdown rendering and browser refresh. You could take it as a source of inspiration.